# Gradle not imported dependency with ext:pom

Tags: gradle, dependencies, geotools

I want import library org.geotools.

Added raw  `compile group: 'org.geotools', name: 'geotools', version: '16.1'`
or `compile group: 'org.geotools', name: 'geotools', version: '16.1', ext: 'pom'`
and repo:

```
repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    maven { url 'http://repo.boundlessgeo.com/main' }
    maven { url "http://download.osgeo.org/webdav/geotools/" }
    maven { url "http://download.java.net/maven/2" }
    maven { url "http://repo.opengeo.org" }
    mavenCentral()
}
```

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 47s
but in external libraries it not found.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I not a gradle user but don't you need to add some actual dependencies?

For GeoTools I usually start with at least some of [these](http://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/library/index.html):

- [gt-main](http://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/library/main/index.html)
- [gt-metadata](http://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/library/metadata/index.html)
- [gt-referencing](http://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/library/referencing/index.html)

and a [datasource](http://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/library/data/index.html) or 2.

Comment: added     compile group: 'org.geotools', name: 'gt-epsg-extension', version: '19.0'
 compile 'org.geotools:gt-main:20-SNAPSHOT'

The result is the same