# how to use geotools in android (how add geotools lib to android)?

Tags: android, geotools

I want to use the Geotools library in my android code. But the library is not being added correctly. To use the library I used the following address and acted accordingly.
"[Gradle not imported dependency with ext:pom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50738332/gradle-not-imported-dependency-with-extpom)"
I enter the following commands And I get the error below.
please guide me. That's a big problem. I have tried different solutions.
Thanks

```
//// code
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.1.0'
    implementation 'org.osmdroid:osmdroid-android:6.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.10.0'
    implementation 'org.osmdroid:osmdroid-mapsforge:5.5:release@aar'
    implementation 'com.github.MKergall:osmbonuspack:6.4'
    implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-sdk:8.0.1'
    implementation 'org.osmdroid:osmdroid-wms:6.0.2'
    implementation 'org.slf4j:slf4j-android:1.6.1-RC1'
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    //implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
    //implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.87'
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    //implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    //implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.2'
    implementation 'com.github.samanzamani.persiandate:PersianDate:0.7'
    implementation 'ca.rmen:lib-sunrise-sunset:1.1.1'
    implementation 'com.github.beyka:androidtiffbitmapfactory:0.9.8.7'

    //api 'com.vividsolutions:jts-core:1.14.0'
    //api 'com.vividsolutions:jts-io:1.14.0'


    //api ('org.orbisgis:cts:1.5.1') {
       //exclude group: 'org.slf4j'
   // }
    //implementation 'org.orbisgis:cts:1.5.1', {
       // exclude module: 'org.slf4j'
    //}
    //implementation 'org.jdom:jdom:1.1.3'
   //implementation 'net.schmizz:sshj:0.10.0'
    //api 'org.geotools:gt-data:20.0'
    //implementation 'org.geotools:gt-shapefile:20.0'

    implementation 'com.github.beyka:androidtiffbitmapfactory:0.9.8.7'
    implementation 'com.drewnoakes:metadata-extractor:2.12.0'

    /**
    implementation 'org.geotools:gt-main:16.1'
    implementation 'org.geotools:gt-metadata:17.1'
    implementation 'org.geotools:gt-referencing:17.1'
    implementation 'org.geotools:gt-epsg-hsql:2.5.6'
    implementation 'org.geotools:gt-epsg-extension:10.2'
    implementation 'org.geotools:gt-main:16.1'

 */


}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        //maven { url 'http://download.osgeo.org/webdav/geotools/' }
        jcenter()

        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }

        maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
        maven { url "https://dl.bintray.com/caarmen/maven/" }

       // maven { url "http://repo.boundlessgeo.com/main" }
        //maven { url 'https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.geotools/gt-main' }

        mavenLocal()
        maven { url 'http://repo.boundlessgeo.com/main' }
        maven { url "http://download.osgeo.org/webdav/geotools/" }
        maven { url "http://download.java.net/maven/2" }
        maven { url "http://repo.opengeo.org" }
        mavenCentral()



    }
}

//////error
ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not find jai_core.jar (javax.media:jai_core:1.1.3).
Show Details
Affected Modules: app


ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not find jai_core.jar (javax.media:jai_core:1.1.3).
Show Details
Affected Modules: app
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android App build on geotools library missing native java libs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8256845/android-app-build-on-geotools-library-missing-native-java-libs)